# Positioning of Drupal error messages

Tags: html, css, drupal

i'm developing a site in Drupal and stumbled upon something strange. Error messages in my Dev and Prod environments act different.

I'm setting a form validation error using "form_set_error". While in my development mode the error message goes to the content_header part of the html, the message in my Prod environment goes in the content itself, messing up my CSS.

It's something small but a bit of a nuisance, and I couldn't find any configuration of it anywhere. Some configuration must be in charge of that and for some reason different in my two environments. If anyone happens to know why this happens or where I could fix it I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Are there differences in the theme between dev and prod? Are you using custom/contrib theme? Which major version of Drupal are you using?

You might start by look at where `$messages` are printed in page.tpl.php

Comment: Thanks. It's a custom theme, but the same for both dev and prod. I copied and overran the entire project with the dev code so it should be the same. Using Drupal 6. according to page.tpl.php the messages are printed within the header, as i'd like them to be..

Comment: If the messages appear in the same place within the HTML, then that leaves CSS.  I didn't quite understand your response. Did you recopy and it is now fixed?